# Client (JRE) read server (node) variables directly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to set up a server where clients can connect and essentially "raise their hand", which lights up for every client, but only one at a time. I currently just use the express module to send a POST response on button-click. The server takes it as JSON and writes it to a file. All the clients are constantly requesting this file to check the status to see if the channel is clear.

I suspect there is a more streamlined approach for this, but I do not know what modules or methods might be best. Can the server push variables to the clients in some way, instead of the clients constantly requesting a file? Then the client script can receive the variable and change the page elements accordingly?

Comment: You can use server push. But a bidirectional communication process like WebSockets may be more appropriate for this.

Comment: Ah, yea I forgot to mention I have socket.io as well for a small chat window, which is a side function of the project.

Comment: Great! It'd be perfect if you can reuse it to send messages with "user X raised their hand" from server to client. Use any appropriate format for this (e.g., `{ type: "hand-raise", userId: "12345" }`)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this kind of task is done by using WebSockets. Since you already have `socket.io` set up, it'd be great to reuse it.

From the server, start emitting different messages:

```js
socket.emit("hand", { userId: <string> });
```

From the client, listen to the new event and invoke whatever the appropriate behavior is:

```js
socket.on("hand", (payload) => {
  // payload.userId contains user ID
});
```

Comment: I see, I wasn't sure how to correlate the functions between server and client js. If I understand correctly, socket.emit/on(IDENTIFIER. As long as the identifier is the same the socket will handle the communication?

Comment: Exactly. This identifier is actually an event name. So, you're basically creating new custom events, along with `"message"`, `"error"` etc.

Comment: follow up question if you see this. I saw in the documentation how to have the server send to a specific user with io.to(X,y), but I couldn't find how to have a user send a message specifically to the server. Or maybe emit just goes to the server and I am overthinking how socket.io works?

Comment: I guess, you'll have to ask another question for this